# Is it better to use a prepared Select statement when you are only doing one select?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am currently writing a CRUD class in PHP using PDO.

I like the security that prepared statements provide, but I have heard that they also prevent databases like mysql from using the queryCache.

Is it better to use a prepared Select statement when you are only doing one select at a time? or would just $pdo->quote() suffice the security standpoint (or have any other advantages like caching?).

All my update, delete and inserts are done using prepared statements already. I am just curious about the selects.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MySQLPerformanceBlog.com did some benchmarks in an article about "[Prepared Statements](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/08/02/mysql-prepared-statements/)."  Peter Zaitsev wrote:

> I’ve done a simple benchmark (using
>   SysBench) to see performance of simple
>   query (single row point select) using
>   standard statement, prepared statement
>   and have it served from query cache.
>   Prepared statements give 2290
>   queries/sec which is significantly
>   better than 2000 with standard
>   statements but it is still well below
>   4470 queries/sec when results are
>   served from query cache.

This seems to say that the "overhead" of using prepared statements is that they are 14.5% *faster* than using a straight query execution, at least in this simple test.  The relative difference probably diminishes with a more complex query or a larger result set.

It seems counter-intuitive that prepared queries would be faster, given the double round-trip to the server and other factors.  Peter's benchmark lacks details.  Anyway, you should run your own tests, because the type of query you run, and your environment and hardware, are definitely important factors.

As for Query Cache, it was true in the past that prepared statements were incompatible with caching query results, but this was changed.  See "[How the Query Cache Operates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-how.html)" in the MySQL documentation:

> Before MySQL 5.1.17, prepared
>   statements do not use the query cache.
>   Beginning with 5.1.17, prepared
>   statements use the query cache under
>   certain conditions, which differ
>   depending on the preparation method: ...

The documentation goes on to describe these conditions.  Go read it.

I do recommend using prepared statements for `SELECT` queries.  Quoting variables as you interpolate them into SQL statements can be effective if you do it consistently.  But even quoting may have some subtle security vulnerabilities, e.g. with multi-byte character sets (see MySQL bug #[8378](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8378)).  It's easier to use prepared queries in a secure way in these cases.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use prepared statements. I seriously doubt you will run into performance problems with prepared statements running much slower than just a regular literal query. However, on mysql, you appear to be correct. I would opt for prepared statements nevertheless.

Here is one reference:
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/08/02/mysql-prepared-statements/

Although, if you are worried about caching, you might want to look at things like [memcached](http://www.danga.com/memcached/).

Comment: This purely for the sure fire security then? Because it look like there are even more performance draw backs then I thought.

Comment: I think security is enough reason. The performance issue, I consider to be a bug in MySQL.

Comment: And a bug that will be fixed probably sooner than later. Prepared statements have become best practice pretty much across the board for dbms abstraction layers.

Answer (score 1):

This is my understanding, as confirmed by discussion from: [here](http://www.usenet-forums.com/php-general/394519-php-prepared-statement.html)

> A normal query is taken as a single
>   string, parsed, executed, and
>   returned. End of story. A prepared
>   statement is taken as a template
>   string, parsed, and cached. It then
>   has variables passed into it, almost
>   like a function call.
>
> Caching the query once tends to cost a
>   little bit more than just executing it
>   straight. The savings come in later
>   calls, when you skip the compilation
>   step. You save per repeated query the
>   amount of the compilation.

So, in short, on MySQL, if you're executing a query once, preparing it just adds a needless extra amount of processing.

Answer (score 1):

Prepared statements are generally considered to be better practice.

I would suggest reading the [MySql article](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html) on prepared statements and their practicalities and advantages over conventional plain-vanilla interpolated stringy queries.

Comment: From the article
> Sometimes prepared statements can actually be slower than regular queries. The reason for this is that there are two round-trips to the server, which can slow down simple queries that are only executed a single time.In cases like that, one has to decide if it is worth trading off.

Comment: It doesn't seem very clear what is better practice in such a common situation.

Comment: Why not, prepared statement follow a best-practice workflow internally (it is hoped), which, while may be buggy and exploitable at the same time will 'generally' lead to better coding practices and reduce the potential for the introduction of human error.
I did say 'generally'

Answer (score 1):

Are you only doing a select "once" in the application lifetime, or "once" per call to the function?

Because if the latter, you should still benefit from the caching in the prepared statement anyway.

Comment: once" per call to the function.

How would that work if the templates generated from each call are different?

Sometimes they have limits, joins and where clauses and othertimes not. If the templates are rewritten each call they will still be cached?

Comment: @unknown: No.  MySQL Query Cache is a cached result set, keyed by the query string that generated that result.  If you change the query at all -- e.g. even insignificant changes to whitespace or parenthesis -- it doesn't use the cached data from before.

Answer (score 0):

Just a reminder that MySQL > 5.1.17 [does use](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html) the query cache for prepared statements.

From the code POV, i believe prepared statements are, for the most part, the way to go in terms of readability, maintainability, etc...

The one reason not to use them would be expensive queries that get called with some frequency. (queries that take a lot of time to run and have a real benefit on being on the query cache).